# BASH/Linux - Need a command to recursively compress a specific file type within a multiple level directory

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I need to compress a considerable number of pdf and txt files but I want to leave the file structure untouched.  The directories have many, many subdirectories.

When I want to compress files of a specific type in a single directory I run:

```
for i in `find | grep -E "\.pdf$|\.txt$"`; do gzip "$i" ; done
```

but this would take me years to do by hand.

Comment: It looks like you already have a command to do that. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in top-level directory.

```
find . -type f -mmin +1 '(' -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' ')' -exec gzip {} ';'
```

I took the liberty to only gzip files older than 2 minutes, so that it doesn't touch files that are likely to be presently being written to (`mmin +1` does that).

Answer (score 1):

Im not certain why your existing 'command' isnt working. This script should though. Run in a parent directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f| while read FILE
do
  if grep -E "\.pdf$|\.txt$"; then
    gzip ${FILE}
  fi
done
```

Comment: You are right, my original command did work, I just assumed (yes, I know) that it wouldn't as I only tested it in a single directory with no sub directories.  Thank you for your reply :)